# Test for comparing one distribution to a set of distributions from summary statistics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

First of all, I apologize in advance for errors and/or usage of unspecific terms.

Let's say I have the median and IQR for some variable for a "test" dataset and a set of "reference" datasets, and I want to know how different or abnormal the distribution of the variable in the test dataset is in comparison/context of the reference datasets.

The underlying motivation is to identify variables that are sufficiently different enough to warrant further investigation of the validity/quality of the variable in the test dataset. Intuitively, the more heterogeneous the variable in the reference datasets, the less worried I would be about the difference between the test and references (and vice versa).

Let's say the information I have is as follows:

| Dataset | Median | IQR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TEST | 9 | 4 |
| REFERENCE_A | 11 | 4 |
| REFERENCE_B | 14 | 6 |
| REFERENCE_C | 12 | 2 |
| REFERENCE_D | 16 | 3 |
| REFERENCE_E | 14 | 5 |

One test I can imagine is - derived vaguely from ANOVA - finding the ratio between [the variance of difference in medians between the test and reference datasets] and [the within-dataset variance], then using the F-distribution to arrive at a p-value.

$Numerator = ((9-11)^2 + (9-14)^2 + (9-12)^2 + (9-16)^2 + (9-14)^2)/(5-1) = 112/4 = 28$

$Denominator = (4^2 + 4^2 + 6^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 5^5)/(6-1) = 106/5 = 21.2$

$F-statistic = Numerator / Denominator = 28/21.2$

Using scipy, p-value = scipy.stats.f.sf($numerator/denominator, df_n, df_d$) = scipy.stats.f.sf($28/21.2, 4, 5$) = ~$0.377$

Then, I could set some arbitrary level of p, below which I can flag for further investigation.

Please let me know if there's any kernel of merit to this approach, if so, any corrections, and if not, any alternatives.

Thanks!